# notifying parent View Container

Tags: ios, uiview, nsnotifications, uicontainerview

I have a ViewContainer (UIView) and when it's time for the child to disappear I want to tell the Parent to animate the closing.

Is there a notification I can use so that the parent listens for this and animates the close.

```
[self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1

content.view.frame = DocumentViewContainer.frame; // 2
[DocumentViewContainer addSubview:content.view];
[content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"NO", @"ShouldOpenNewView",  nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"closeChildView" object:self userInfo:dic];
```